# Multi-Line Text - Append Changes - Duplicate Entries on Save

Tags: custom-list, duplicate, multiline-text-field, append-changes

Using SharePoint 2013, I have a notes field (multi-line text / append changes) on a custom list being used to capture budgetary information. The notes field was intended to be a running commentary on issues as they arise within a project.

The budget has several batch style updates run from a CSOM JavaScript. Each time the batch update is run, the note entries are duplicated and stamped as entered by the person running the batch update even though the update does nothing to the notes field.

Is there a way to eliminate the duplication of previous entries when no change is applied to the field?

Answer (score 1):

I may have found a solution.

It seems that by not specifying the field's update, the script was defaulting the update value to the previous value. By explicitly telling the update function to send an empty string it seems to prevent duplication.